# Comprobar registros de windows con c#

Tags: c#, windows

estoy haciendo un programa en c# donde tengo que añadir un registro pero quiero comprobar antes que no este ya registrado, he probado con esto pero la verdad es que no tengo mucha idea sobre comprobar registros en c#

```cs
RegistryKey rkSubKey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"Equipo\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\(registro)", false);
```

Y para comprobarlo

```cs
if (rkSubKey != null)
```

¿Alguien que pueda guiarme un poco?

Comment: Cuál es el subkey que desea abrir?

Comment: Sería este AutoItX3.Control (creo que es a lo que te refieres)

Comment: En ese caso, me parece que sería: RegistryKey rkSubKey = Registry.ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey(@"(registro)", false);

Comment: Si, con eso ya estaría solucionado, gracias.